# Why put a comma before "too" when meaning "as well" but not before words that can be used in place of "too?"

Tags: commas

"If I were to go to the market, would you like to come, too?"

How is it that that is correct, while replacing "too" with "as well" would not warrant the same comma before it? They mean the same thing, so why aren't they treated like it?

Comment: I wouldn't put a comma before _too_ either!

Comment: I'd go further than @KateBunting and say that the comma there is simply incorrect.

Comment: Like @KateBunting and Fraser Orr I would say "Yes, why would you?" But then we are all British. See the answer by linguisticturn.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, both the version with a comma and the version without a comma are grammatically *acceptable* for both *too* and *as well.* Especially in the case of *too* (in American English, when it is at the end of the sentence), the decision whether to put a comma is **largely a matter of style,** despite the fact that some speakers detect a difference in meaning. Moreover, the comma seems **far more common in American English than in British English**; indeed, in American English the version with a comma is slightly preferred, while in British English the comma is pretty strongly disfavored (see below).

On the other hand, in the case of *as well*, both American and British English strongly disfavor the comma, although in American English the disfavoring is not as strong as in British English.

Thus, especially in American English, but even in British English, the comma is much more acceptable before *too* than before *as well*. An obvious follow-up to your question might be to ask why there is this difference between *too* and *as well*. At the moment at least, I have to say that I don't know. All I can say is that I see little hope in being able to find a reason from the semantics and grammar of contemporary English. (In the semantics and grammar of contemporary English, when *as well* and *too* are placed at the end of a sentence, they are indeed extremely similar.) Therefore, the reason is likely to lie within diachronic (historical) linguistics rather than in synchronic linguistics (the latter views linguistic phenomena only at a given time, usually the present).

**Discussion**

***Too* vs. *as well***

In the usage we are discussing, *too* and *as well* function as **focusing modifiers of the additive type,** a group which also includes *in addition, also,* and *even* ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), pp. 592-595). While *as well* and *too* in this function are very similar, they are not completely interchangeable. For example, in

*Sue bought a CD **too**.*

the *too* can be readily replaced by *as well*; however, in

*I **too** think the proposal has merit.*

the replacement is possible, but not as felicitous (CGEL, 593).

**The comma before *too***

About the comma before *too,* here is what *The Chicago Manual Of Style* (CMoS) FAQ had to say [(here)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112040819/www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas/faq0004.html):

> Q. Please help clarify a debate over what I see as a groundless but persistent carryover from high-school English classes: the comma-before-too “rule.” The rule goes something like this: When “too” is used in the sense of “also,” use a comma before and after “too” in the middle of a sentence and a comma before “too” at the end of a sentence. I am editing a work of fiction in which the author has rigidly applied the rule. I have just as rigidly deleted the commas. My managing editor believes that a comma is needed when “too” refers to an item in a list and has the sense of “in addition” (e.g., “I like apples and bananas, too.”), but she would omit the comma when “too” refers to the subject of the sentence (e.g., “Oh, you like apples and bananas? I like apples and bananas too.”). My managing editor’s rule helps make a useful distinction, but I am still wondering whether the comma is ever grammatically justified.
>
> A. A comma can do some work in making the meaning of a sentence clear, but to claim two different meanings for *I like apples and bananas too* with and without a comma before *too* puts too much pressure on the comma. Out of context, neither version would be perfectly clear. To make the different meanings more apparent, short of additional context, you’d have to be more explicit:
>
> > I, too, like apples and bananas.
> > I like not only apples but bananas too.
>
> Use commas with *too* only when you want to emphasize an abrupt change of thought:
>
> > He didn’t know at first what hit him, but then, too, he hadn’t ever walked in a field strewn with garden rakes.
>
> In most other cases, commas with this short adverb are unnecessary (an exception being sentences that begin with *too*—in the sense of *also*—a construction some writers would avoid as being too awkward).

Having said that, if you search the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for *too* at the end of the sentence, you find lots of hits both with and without the preceding comma, and even if you constrain the search to academic sources only: for academic sources, 938 hits (45%) are without a comma, and 1149 (55%) are with. Here is a snapshot of some of them:

[image]

If a similar search is performed in the *British National Corpus* [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), the version with a comma is far more rare: among academic sources, 287 (84%) are without a comma, and 55 (16%) are with one.

**The comma before *as well***

In contrast, if you do a similar search on COCA for *as well,* almost none of the hits come with a preceding comma: for academic sources, 5991 (95%) are without a comma, and 320 (5%) are with.

[image]

The one exception in the preceding list is

*Arts and crafts projects can easily coordinate with the theme of the projects, as well.*

On BNC, the breakdown (again for academic sources) is 358 (99%) without, and 3 (1%) with.